# On 22.04 LTS, I have an app named "Software" and another named "Ubuntu Software". They seem redundant

Tags: 22.04

When I look at both apps, they seem to do exactly the same thing.  Though the featured software on the initial screen is different.  Can I delete one of these apps?

Comment: **Probably** one of these apps (I think it's "Software") is the thing previously known as "GNOME Software" and the other (I think "Ubuntu Software") is what was previously known as "Snap Store". The difference is that Snap Store can install only snap applications, while GNOME Software can also install software distributed as standard .deb packages from Ubuntu repositiories. This could also explain the different software selections on the initial screen.

Comment: In the title I mentioned 22.04 LTS - which is Ubuntu.

Comment: Raj, I am sure your answer is correct.  Is there a way in this interface to mark your reply as the correct answer and close this question?

Comment: I have posted it as an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: if you installed Flatpak store you will see (software) and Ubuntu software.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how it is in 22.04, as I still use 20.04, but here I have "Software" (also known as "GNOME Software") and "Snap Store". Probably in 22.04 "Snap Store" got renamed to "Ubuntu Software".

The difference is that Snap Store can install only snap applications, while GNOME Software can also install software distributed as standard .deb packages from Ubuntu repositories. This could also explain the different software selections on the initial screen.

(By the way, Snap Store is a snap application itself, while GNOME Software is installed as a .deb package :))

Of course you can delete one of them. Probably you can even delete both of them and install software from command line, using commands `snap` for snap packages and `apt` for .deb packages.

As far as I remember, only Snap Store (aka Ubuntu Software) is installed in Ubuntu by default, directly after OS installation.

Answer (score 1):

A fresh Ubuntu 22.04 install has only one item, "Software Center". It is a snap version of the Gnome Software application, customized for Ubuntu

In older versions, both were installed, one with the name "Software", the other with the name "Snap Store". If you have an version 22.04 that was upgraded, the latter would have been renamed "Ubuntu software". If your 22.04 is a fresh install, then you installed Software by yourself.

You can uninstall either of these app. Ubuntu Software is the default for Ubuntu, so preferably you remove "Software". You can do so in "Ubuntu Software".

Comment: Well, that did not work for me. "Software" did not show up in "Ubuntu software" for me. However - uninstalling from the terminal worked: 
$ sudo apt-get remove gnome-software